# How to calculate Gini for different Splits in a loop?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I have a dataframe which includes columns as Split, Target, Score. I want to calculate gini for each split of data. And i want to return gini for each split. I am using below code. How to fix this?

```
Splits = ['Cash', 'NonCash', 'New']

for i in Splits:
    
    Target = df[df['Split'] == i]['Target']
    Score = df[df['Split'] == i]['Score']

    def Gini(Target, Score):
        ROC = roc_auc_score(Target, Score)
        Gini = ROC*2-1
return Gini
```

My Data like this:

```
d={
    'Split' :['Cash','Cash','NonCash','New','New'],
    'Target':[0,0,1,0,1],
    'Score':[69,76,74,89,62]
}

df=pd.DataFrame(d, columns=['Split','Target','Score'])
```

Expected Result is calculating gini value for each split and creating a gini parameter like Gini_Cash, Gini_NonCash, Gini_New.

Comment: Please post sample input dataframe with expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
d={
    'Split' :['Cash','Cash','NonCash','New','New'],
    'Target':[0,0,1,0,1],
    'Score':[69,76,74,89,62]
}

df=pd.DataFrame(d, columns=['Split','Target','Score'])


Splits = ['Cash', 'NonCash', 'New']
gin=[]

def Gini(Target, Score):
    ROC = roc_auc_score(Target, Score)
    Gini_1 = ROC*2-1
    return Gini_1

for i in Splits:
    
    Target = df[df['Split'] == i]['Target']
    Score = df[df['Split'] == i]['Score']
    gin.append(Gini(Target,Score))
```

You'll get a list of Gini scores